# Firefox change adress bar behavior to google search

Tags: firefox, address-bar

Is there a way to change the behavior of the address bar in firefox 38? 
I would like to be able to type in the bar and it autocomplete from google, instead of my history. 
I no previously this was accomplished by changing keyword.url, but this no longer exists in the newer version of Firefox. 
Is there a new method someone has found to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the source of the suggestions can be changed, but the default search engine can be changed by going to Settings>Customize>Search (on Android) or [Magnifying glass]>Change search settings (on desktop).

This might result in different suggestions. (I infer that you're using desktop, since Android Firefox seems to give decent suggestions, only the wrong search engine.)

I found these instructions out on https://duck.co/help/desktop/firefox by searching "how to make duckduckgo default search engine in firefox on android", on DuckDuckGo, in case you want to make further discoveries along the same route.